# Issue with a new PC build randomly restarting

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, whea-logger

I built a new PC yesterday and since having issues rebooting randomly.

Here is the configuration...

- AORUS X570 Ultra
- Ryzen 9 5950x Processor
- AORUS 3080 10G GPU

What I looked so far,

- Temperatures are in good ranges(hovering around 43)
- Updated all the drivers installing Gigabyte motherboard utility
- Windows Events

I found in Windows Events that there is a fatal hardware error happening and is causing the reboots.

[image]

The WHEA logger error seems to be the culprit.

```
A fatal hardware error has occurred.

Reported by component: Processor Core
Error Source: Machine Check Exception
Error Type: Cache Hierarchy Error
Processor APIC ID: 4

The details view of this entry contains further information.
```

Details of the error is

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WHEA-Logger" Guid="{c26c4f3c-3f66-4e99-8f8a-39405cfed220}" /> 
  <EventID>18</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-10-03T16:41:13.4596030Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4583</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{b4539d52-aa42-4902-acda-b0d1a0377c1d}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4844" ThreadID="6520" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-SLU6G2T</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-19" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="ErrorSource">3</Data> 
  <Data Name="ApicId">4</Data> 
  <Data Name="MCABank">5</Data> 
  <Data Name="MciStat">0xbaa0000000030150</Data> 
  <Data Name="MciAddr">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="MciMisc">0xd01a0ffe00000000</Data> 
  <Data Name="ErrorType">9</Data> 
  <Data Name="TransactionType">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Participation">256</Data> 
  <Data Name="RequestType">5</Data> 
  <Data Name="MemorIO">256</Data> 
  <Data Name="MemHierarchyLvl">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Timeout">256</Data> 
  <Data Name="OperationType">256</Data> 
  <Data Name="Channel">256</Data> 
  <Data Name="Length">936</Data> 
  <Data Name="RawData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ata> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Searching for these error resulted in some links, but none of them proved to be helpful and I am not sure how to decipher the above error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Likely a driver issue -- that needs an update.  Recommend: Update the BIOS first.  Then, update any drivers afterwards.  Curious: What is associated with process ID 4844 running as NT Authority (LocalService)?  Until this is resolved, I would recommend disabling any third-party security/anti-virus programs.

Comment: I updated the bios and it is on latest. I updated all motherboard drivers and GPU. What other drivers should I be looking at? I am using ESET antivirus, but the issue is even before that. But I will disable that till the issue is resolved.

Comment: Reboot often means Blue Screen, check Nirsoft BluescreenView tool what the error message is.

Comment: It is a hardware fault. CPU 4 reported it and seems to be a cache error. MCE **are not** caused by software.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception

Comment: Are you sure you are running the latest bios (F35b) ? This is almost certainly not a software error, so you can save yourself all the trouble with drivers etc. Just make sure you are running that latest bios. If you still get the errors, its likely to be your CPU or motherboard.

Comment: When I am using thier bios tool, the latest I am seeing is F30. May be I should try downloading the image and then load it from file instead of using online service. Will try that. Thanks for the info @Silbee

Comment: You have a faulty IC. Either main memory or cache memory. Don't overclock. If two main memory sticks remove one then the other too test. Cache memory is soldered. Run Windows' Memory diagnostic (type memory in settings).

Comment: Just updated the BIOS to 35b which is the latest. For some reason the utility is not showing the latest version. I downloaded the file and updated. Fingers crossed. Will watch a day and try the memory check.

Comment: @TejaKantamneni Hi, did you have any luck resolving the issue ?